# Customizing comments in wordpress theme (shaken grid premium 212)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove two fields (copy and paste password fields) from comments in shaken grid premium, i tried  `<?php comments_template( '', true );  ?>` in single.php and page.php but still don't work, 
see here ...

http://www.dgrdo.com/a-post-with-the-minimal-post-template/

thanks.

Comment: Not sure about the `shaken grid premium` but all themes must have hooked the actual wordpress comment template..So there must be file related to comment template hook somewhere in your template folder....

Comment: I could not find any kind hook yet, thanks for reply,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment box is not a part of the shaken grid premium template, its a plugin called 'Spam Free Wordpress' and the reason that this plugin is made is because of that password function.

I think the best thing to do is to de-activate the plugin and download some other plugin. Or just use the one from the shaken grid premium him self.